# Angular controller in javascript namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm new in Angular and I made development the following code:

```
(function (Field, $, undefined) {

    Field.GetDataSourceList = function () {

        $http.post(Field.UrlGetDataSourceList, {}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
    };

    Field.GetFieldTypeList = function () {

        $http.post(Field.UrlGetFieldTypeList, {}).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
    };

    Field.TheField = function ($scope) {

        $scope.Model = function () {
            $scope.DataSourceSecected = {};
            $scope.DataSourceList = {};

            $scope.Id = "";
            $scope.Name = "";

            $scope.FieldTypeSelected = {};
            $scope.FieldTypeList = {};

            $scope.SecctionId = "";
            $scope.Order = "";
        };

        $scope.Add = function () {
            $scope.Model.latestValue = $scope.Model.newValue;
            $scope.Model.newValue = "";
        };
    };

    Field.SetUrl = function (data) {

        Field.UrlGetDataSourceList = data.UrlGetDataSourceList;
        Field.UrlGetFieldTypeList = data.UrlGetDataSourceList;
    };

    Field.Init = function () {

        var theField = new Field.TheField();

        theField.$inject = ["$scope"];

        theField.Model.DataSourceList = Field.GetDataSourceList;
        theField.Model.FieldTypeList = Field.GetFieldTypeList;
    };

}(window.Field = window.Field || {}, jQuery));
```

In my page I need call some functions like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            Field.SetUrl({

                UrlGetDataSourceList: "@Url.Action("GetDataSourceList", "DataSource")",
                UrlGetFieldTypeList: "@Url.Action("GetFieldTypeList", "Field")"
            });

            Field.Init();

        });

    </script>
```

But I have been investigating on internet and I think that Angular is a little bit different:

I would like to call some functions that I have on my angular controller, for example make this:

```
var theField = new Field.TheField();
theField.$inject = ["$scope"];

theField.Model.DataSourceList = Field.GetDataSourceList;
theField.Model.FieldTypeList = Field.GetFieldTypeList;
```

But not works ... Help ...

I make like this because I like have a nice structure of my project ...

PD: I come from Knockout ...

Comment: Without trying to be rude, it's obvious that you have come from a different framework background because what you have written doesn't look like angular at all. May I suggest you read more about angular before writing any more code. [This course](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/) worked really nicely for me.

Comment: yea... this is bad... you should probably start of with more of a module pattern of controllers like Angular was meant to be written in

Comment: Okey, I does not have any option that learn about it ...